# Why change the name of getters and setters in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c-2.0

I've just learned that you can modify the automatically generated getter and setter names for Objective-C properties

```
// boolean property of "door" object in game
@property (strong, nonatomic, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;
```

I understand how `isOpen` is a preferable getting to just `open`, but why not just change the property name to `isOpen`?

Why would having the setter also named `isOpen` be not desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is best appreciated if we use [] syntax

```
    if ([door isOpen])
       doSomething;
    else
       [door setOpen:YES];
```

reads more like plain English than

```
    if ([door isOpen])
       doSomething;
    else
       [door setIsOpen:YES];
```

in modern-day dot syntax the difference is a little lost

```
    if (door.isOpen)
       doSomething;
    else
       door.open = YES;
```

vs

```
    if (door.isOpen)
       doSomething;
    else
       door.isOpen = YES;
```